# Add a date tooltip for "Migrated From"

Tags: feature-request, migration, timestamps

Currently, questions that are migrated have a date tooltip on the "Migrated To" message on the original site. I'd like to see a similar tooltip on the "Migrated From" message on the destination site.

While this information is visible in the edit history, it isn't available when the question has not been edited yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this request has already implement. There is a timestamp after the Migrated From message on the destination site, for example [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29466/how-to-force-browsers-not-to-reload-recently-seen-page-after-resume)